# Store settimeout id from nodejs in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, settimeout

I am running a web application using express and nodejs. I have a request to a particular endpoint in which I use settimeout to call a particular function repeatedly after varying time intervals.

For example

```
router.get ("/playback", function(req, res) {
    // Define callback here ...
    ....

    var timeoutone = settimeout(callback, 1000);
    var timeouttwo = settimeout(callback, 2000);
    var timeoutthree = settimeout(callback, 3000);
});
```

The settimeout function returns an object with a circular reference. When trying to save this into mongodb i get a stack_overflow error. My aim is to be able to save these objects returned by settimeout into the database.

I have another endpoint called cancel playback which when called, will retrieve these timeout objects and call cleartimeout passing them in as an argument. How do I go about saving these timeout objects to the database ? Or is there a better way of clearing the timeouts than having to save them to the database. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save live JavaScript objects in the database! Maybe you can store a string or JSON  or similar reference to them, but not the actual object, and you cannot reload them later.

**Edit:** Also, I've just noticed you're using setTimeout for repeating stuff. If you need to repeat it on regular intervals, why not use `setInterval` instead?

Here is a simple solution, that would keep indexes in memory:

```
var timeouts = {};
var index = 0;

// route to set the timeout somewhere
router.get('/playback', function(req, res) {
  timeouts['timeout-' + index] = setTimeout(ccb, 1000);
  storeIndexValueSomewhere(index)
  .then(function(){
    res.json({timeoutIndex: index});
    index++;
  });
}
// another route that gets timeout indexes from that mongodb somehow
req.get('/playback/indexes', handler);

// finally a delete route
router.delete('/playback/:index', function(req, res) {
  var index = 'timeout-' + req.params.index;
  if (!timeouts[index]) {
    return res.status(404).json({message: 'No job with that index'});
  } else {
    timeouts[index].cancelTimeout();
    timeouts[index] = undefined;
    return res.json({message: 'Removed job'});
  }
});
```

But this probably would not scale to many millions of jobs.

A more complex solution, and perhaps more appropriate to your needs (depends on your `playback` job type) could involve job brokers or message queues, clusters and workers that subscribe to something they can listen to for their own job cancel signals etc.

I hope this helps you a little to clear up your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Shall look into message queues. For now, I shall go with the above given solution. I am using setTimeout because i do not playback events at regular intervals but predetermined time differences. The code I used in the question was just an example. Thank you !

Comment: To add to this, JSON.stringify(timer) for use in a doc will result in `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.